# Does outlook ever convert email bodies to attachments?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, mailing-lists

I subscribe to the "Quickfix-users" mailing list.  This mailing list has the option to email subscribers each conversation.

Most of the time what outlook shows me is an empty email with the actual message as an attachment with a `.c` extension.  [image: An example can be seen here].

If I open the attachment it does contain the message.  Oddly this behaviour isn't consistent.

Is this outlook doing this or is this just a quirk of the mailing list software?

Comment: Which version of MS Outlook? Do you have Outlook configured to "Read all standard mail in plane text"? Are you behind a UTM? Lastly, this maybe an intentional result of the QuickFIX messaging engine...

Comment: @packets, the version is listed in a tag:) Its outlook 2010.  I use HTML for display

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: No. Outlook doesn't convert anything to attachments that don't arrive as attachments. The same behavior occurs when it receives messages from some text messaging equipment (like phones), where the text message arrives as an attachment.

My guess is that the inconsistency you observe has something to do with how Quickfix chooses to package the conversations (perhaps based on length?)